# React js setting the state of a parent component from child Render method

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

**Functionality** : I want to change a property of type object inside Parent Component's state from Child component's render method.

**What I tried so far**: I have passed a method to my child component as prop from parent which in turn sets the state of Parent. Below few lines of code explain what I am trying to achieve.

Within my child component's render method , I have something Like below

```
 <label>{this.setStateKey("title",item,mode)}</label>
 <label>{this.setStateKey("description",item,mode)}</label>
```

within the child's setStateKey method which can take title or description as parameters, I have put the method which gets passed from parent.

```
this.props.changeParentState({title/description},item)
```

In my parent component I have state property of type object which consists of two property title and description

```
this.state = {
  item: {
   title:"",
   descripion:""
  }
}
```

Now inside the changeParentState method of parent component, I am changing the state using spread operator

```
changeParentState=(key,value)=>
{
  if(key === "title")
  {
     this.setState({ item: {
        ...this.state.item,
        title: 'value'
     }});
  }
  if(key === "description")
  {
     this.setState({ item: {
        ...this.state.item,
        description: 'value'
     }});
  }
}
```

**Observed behavior** : The item property doesn't hold the value that is sent as part of title. It always holds only description value (Seems second method call to parent always overrides the first one ).

Could anyone please help me to understand this behavior? May be I need to revisit some react core concepts. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR this first line :

```
<label>{this.setStateKey("title",item,mode)}</label>
```

sets the state to `title` but then the second line :

```
<label>{this.setStateKey("description",item,mode)}</label>
```

overrides that same state to `description`

You can try deleting the second line and see if your state is set to `title` or not

---

Here is a rundown of how your code is executed, first this line :

```
 <label>{this.setStateKey("title",item,mode)}</label>
```

the function `setStateKey()` is called which calls this one `this.props.changeParentState({title/description},item)` and this part of it is executed :

```
if(key === "title")
  {
     this.setState({ item: {
        ...this.state.item,
        title: 'value'
     }});
  }
```

Which sets your state as wanted.
 But then the second line is executed :

```
<label>{this.setStateKey("description",item,mode)}</label>
```

As before the `setStateKey()` is called which executs this function `this.props.changeParentState({title/description},item)` now this part of your code is executed :

```
  if(key === "description")
  {
     this.setState({ item: {
        ...this.state.item,
        description: 'value'
     }});
  }
```

Which overrides your state to this last one.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. You were right that removing the second line sets the parent's  state to Title. Could you please let me know if there is any way  using which I can set the both of the properties of item  ( title and description both) inside parent's state.   To be more precise, I do not want to lose the title property of item while setting the description. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Xero A simple way of doing this is by initializing an array, using the `.push` method to insert your objects, and then use `setState()` to update your initial `item` state